Generated classes for tests with inheritance cause validation error
Using org.openapitools version 7.1, with its help we generate test classes that have inheritance. In this case, the generated class has a static field openapiFields, which should contain a list of all class fields (for verification). But in fact, this list contains only the list of fields of the parent class, which naturally causes a validation error.
Open API yaml file fragment:
    DataText:
      type: object
      required:
        - textValue
      properties:
        textValue:
          type: string
      allOf:
        - $ref: '#/components/schemas/ItemData'
    ItemData:
      type: object
      properties:
        dataId:
          type: integer
          description: data id
        dataTypeId:
          type: integer
          description: data type id
        type:
          type: string
          description: Discriminator property for ItemData.
      discriminator:
        propertyName: type
        mapping:
          DataText: '#/components/schemas/DataText'

Fragment of the generated class:
public class DataText extends ItemData {
  public static final String SERIALIZED_NAME_TEXT_VALUE = "textValue";
  @SerializedName(SERIALIZED_NAME_TEXT_VALUE)
  private String textValue;
  ...
  static {
    // a set of all properties/fields (JSON key names)
    openapiFields = new HashSet<String>();
    openapiFields.add("dataId");
    openapiFields.add("dataTypeId");
    openapiFields.add("type");

    // a set of required properties/fields (JSON key names)
    openapiRequiredFields = new HashSet<String>();
    openapiRequiredFields.add("textValue");
  }

Question: What should I do to ensure that the names of the fields of the descendant class are also included in list openapiFields?
I read the documentation for the openapi-generator-maven-plugin plugin and tried changing its settings, but unfortunately I didn't get any results... I searched for a solution to a similar problem on the Internet, but so far without success.

This seems to be a known issue: https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/issues/17306 . Also, have you tried setting disallowAdditionalPropertiesIfNotPresent=false? It might be a workaround for your problem.

I tried turning off the disallowAdditionalPropertiesIfNotPresent option. Yes, the generated file has lost the check of fields from the openapiFields list. But a new error appeared: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Class cz.tacr.elza.test.controller.vo.DataText declares multiple JSON fields named 'additionalProperties'; conflict is caused by fields cz.tacr.elza.test.controller.vo.DataText#additionalProperties and cz.tacr.elza.test.controller.vo.ItemData#additionalProperties
